# how to create the new line character

Tags: python, apache

I am  a beginner to python. I have installed the python34 and xampp 1.8.0 and enabled in the httpd.conf as AddHandler cgi-script.cgi.pl.asp.py 
Started with simple code as below ;

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print ('Hello World \n')
print ( 'new world' )
print ('\n')
if ( 6 > 5) :
    print ("greater")
```

And executed this code in the local host as http://localhost/cgi-bin/example.py

It's giving the output as

> Hello World new world greater

Without the break line in between the words. What did I miss?
 out put i needed

```
Hello world
new world
greater
```

Comment: I assume you're looking at the result in the browser and you have no idea what HTML is? Look at the source code of the page, not the rendered page.

Comment: can u plz explain more specifically

Comment: why print ('\n') won't work?

Comment: @user092, because `'\n'` is shell, Python or C/C++ character but definitely not HTML. If you want a new line, use `<br/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For html 5 use `print('<br>')` or `print('<br />')`.

For xhtml use `print('<br />')`.

For html 4 use `print('<br>')`.

Answer (score 0):

\n is the newline in most contexts, however in html, the 
 tag functions as the newline.

Answer (score 0):

When you print `\n` it will print a newline. However, since I assume you are looking at the output in your browser, HTML ignores the newlines in the HTML code. To print a newline in HTML you have to use the *break* tag, which is `<br />`. So

```
print('<br />')
```

will display a newline in your HTML document.